# Current limiting circuit: Need for replacing the pass transistor with MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, analog, bjt, current-limiting

[image]

The [article](https://www.radiolocman.com/shem/schematics.html?di=113034) says "*The circuit provides an approximate constant current at high voltages, but it doesn’t enter regulation until it reaches nearly 60V due to the base current the transistor requires. With a MOSFET, you can use smaller biasing resistors, and the circuit comes into regulation at a much lower terminal voltage.*

I dont see any change in current limit whether i keep the biasing resistors 100k or 2k. Infact, the input voltage at which the current regulation kicks in can be adjusted by these biasing resistors, contrary to what the article states. **What am I missing here?**

Attached hereby the simulation results: By reducing the base resistor to 2k, the same circuit can achieve current limit at a lower input voltage. **I have no clue why the article introduces the need for MOSFET.**

[image]

Comment: The article discusses a *regulator*, not a *limiter*. It seems to not be in regulation, for the large value resistor, below the voltage marked by the cursor.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Yes, agree-It talks about regulation. But my doubt still remains. What is lacking in the transistor version of the circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What am I missing here?*

The article words you copied seem reasonable; I'll explain...

It looks like it performs current limiting at about 40 mA. I say this because the 13 Ω resistor needs to develop about 0.5 volts across it to start activating the 2N3904 at the onset of regulation. That means a collector current through the MJD50 of around 0.5 volts ÷ 13 = 0.038 amps. So, I've called it 40 mA.

If you then look at the [data sheet for the MJD50](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mjd47_fcs-d.pdf) you'll see that it's current gain is about 80: -

[image]

That means a base current of 500 μA is required.

But, that base current has to flow through R2 and R3 (100 kΩ in total) hence, the volt drop across those resistors will be 50 volts. This means that the supply voltage will need to be 50 volts plus two BE diode drops. Call it 52 volts.

OK so the article says 60 volts and that seems very reasonable. Maybe you are not simulating with a device that behaves like the MJD50?

Comment: Agree, for the given R2/R3, the min supply voltage is around 50-60V.
 But I can very well change R2 and R3 to a lower value and get the required base current at a lower supply voltage.

Comment: Then you sacrifice performance at the higher voltages because there is a significantly greater element of base current shunted away to ground by the 2N3904 and this creates a significantly less than perfect constant current circuit @DivyaK.S

Comment: Yes, For  lower R2/R3, there will be a wider variations in 2N3904 collector current as supply voltage changes. But so does for the MOSFET circuit!

Comment: I think it might mean physically smaller (lower power) resistors. That's the only thing that can make sense. A MOSFET doesn't take a base current hence, it will start to regulate at a lower voltage and there will be a fraction of the current through the resistors hence, lower (smaller) power @DivyaK.S